# Execute method when mouse is clicked outside the form

Tags: c#, click, mouse

I'd like to have a method executed whenever left mouse button is clicked in a another application, and another method executed whenever left mouse button is released. I've searched around, and the only solutions I can find eather don't work, or is too complicated for me to modify. Could someone help me with this? (C#)

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean _outside the form_? Outside the currently open form but still inside the main form of your application or on another application?

Comment: Sorry, in a another application.

Comment: "or is too complicated for me to modify" Sorry, capturing a click outside of your application is complicated code.  The most reliable method will be through a low level mouse hook via WH_MOUSE_LL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global mouse hook for that. ( http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C )

It is easy to implement, just download the Source Files [Version 2 (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook/globalhook2_src.zip)]. To play with it (I just tried and it worked for me), it does what you need to do and and more, and it is easy to modify.

Comment: I've already tried that one, but I come to a `throw new Win32Exception(errorCode);` with errorcode 126 in the `EnsureSubscribedToGlobalMouseEvents`-method in HookManager.Callbacks.cs. I've searched around about this too, but havent had any luck...

Comment: I actually found the answer to that. The code was based on pre-.NET4 which don't work anymore.
I changed out the marshal in `s_MouseHookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(
                    WH_MOUSE_LL,
                    s_MouseDelegate,
                    Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(
                        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0]),
                    0);` for mar in `var mar = LoadLibrary("user32.dll");` and added a PInv for freelibrary.